Reference request: To find a proof of the fact that cuspidal characters vanish on non-primary conjugacy classes of finite general linear groups
Let $\chi$ be a cuspidal character of finite general linear group $GL(n,q)$. We call a conjugacy class of $GL(n,q)$ to be non-primary if the characteristic polynomial of its elements is divisible by more than one irreducible polynomial over $F_q[x]$. We know that if C is such a class, then $\chi(c) = 0, \forall \ c \in C.$
Can anyone suggest a reference that includes proof of this fact. I have already tried to go through the famous paper by J.A.Green, but could not get much idea. Is there any book/paper that contains an explicit proof for this. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.
